# Timecop and Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-2.0, timecop

Can anyone suggest why this spec fails using Timecop 0.6.1 and Ruby 2.0.0?

(It passes using Timecop 0.4.5 and Ruby 1.9.3)

```
require 'timecop'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Class do
  it "freezes time" do
    Timecop.freeze Date.new(2012,7,1) do
      expect(Date.today).to eq(Date.new 2012,7,1)
    end
  end
end
```

Which results in:

```
$ rspec spec/models/time_cop_spec.rb 

Failures:

  1) Class freezes time
     Failure/Error: expect(Date.today).to eq(Date.new 2012,7,1)

       expected: Sun, 01 Jul 2012
            got: Thu, 02 May 2013

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -Sun, 01 Jul 2012
       +Thu, 02 May 2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very clear and consise answer to this (and a pull request to fix it) on [Timecop's GitHub Repo](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/issues/83#issuecomment-17766811).

**Short answer**: a change in Bundler version, *not a change in Ruby or Timecop version*, caused the issue.

**Short solution**: Add `require 'date'` to the very top (before `require 'timecop'`).

Thanks to [@micahchalmer](https://twitter.com/micahchalmer) :)

Answer (score 0):

The following passes so it appears `Date.today` support has been dropped in favour of `Time.now.to_date`.

```
require 'timecop'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Class do
  it "freezes time" do
    Timecop.freeze Date.new(2012,7,1) do
      expect(Time.now.to_date).to eq(Date.new 2012,7,1)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't suffering from another issue? I ran you code using ruby 2.0.0-p0, with timecop 0.6.1, and it functioned fine. Ie running the code:

```
require 'timecop'
puts "ruby version: #{RUBY_VERSION}"
puts "timecop version: #{Timecop::VERSION}"

describe Class do
  it "freezes time" do
    Timecop.freeze Date.new(2012,7,1) do
      expect(Date.today).to eq(Date.new 2012,7,1)
    end
  end
end
```

Results in:

```
$ rspec test.rb
ruby version: 2.0.0
timecop version: 0.6.1
.

Finished in 0.00082 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Thanks for this David. More confused now as it passes when I switch `Date.today` for `Time.now.to_date` …